# ReactJS: How to pass props on styled material-UI v5xx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Since `useStyle()` does not work on my material-UI v5xx (can somebody explain why?) , I was confused about how to pass props on this version.

for example for Material-UI v4 we can simply type like this:

```JS
const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const classes=useStyles({open});
  return(....);
}
```

but for v5 I only can use `Styled()` instead of `useStyle()`, so im confused about this part, I want to make a button that display search bar, so  I have created like this:

```JS
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#FFE162",
      contrastText: "black",
    },
  },
});

// in this part i want my open function work
const StyleSearch = styled("div")(({ theme })() => ({
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.4),
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.6),
  },
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  width: "50%",
  [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
    display: (props) => (props.open ? "flex" : "none"),
  },
}));

const Navbar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  function handleOpen() {
    setOpen(true);
  }
  return( 
      <...>
        <StyleSearchBtn onClick={handleOpen} />);
      <.../>
}
```

as you can see the `open` is not set how do pass that to the props.

Comment: Add the prop and use `{ theme, open }` as usual.

Comment: <StyleSearchBtn onClick={handleOpen} open={open}  />)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not compatible with the new version of React, as you can check on their [documentation](https://mui.com/styles/basics/)

> ⚠️ @mui/styles is the legacy styling solution for MUI. It is deprecated in v5. It depends on JSS as a styling solution, which is not used in the @mui/material anymore. If you don't want to have both emotion & JSS in your bundle, please refer to the @mui/system documentation which is the recommended alternative.
>
> ⚠️ @mui/styles is not compatible with React.StrictMode or React 18.

[Here](https://mui.com/system/styled/) you have the documentation needed to use `styled()` correctly.

For your example, you can pass the props normally, like:

```
<StyleSearch props={theme, open} />
```

or

```
<StyleSearch open={open} theme={theme} {...props} />
```